# why does this ['3'|0 + 1] bitwise doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

it seems this only work on "even" numbers:

```
"8"|0 + 1   // 9
"3"|0 + 1   // 3
("3"|0) + 1 // 4
```

but `"3"|0` translates to the Integer `3`.

so what's going on here?
why does the second example acts like this in JS?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/operator_precedence

Comment: @Oded: apparently I was reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators instead of just going to the page you mentioned. sweet! 10x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The precedence of + is higher than |.

So it's parsing like this:

```
"8" | (0 + 1) = "8" | 1 = 9
"3" | (0 + 1) = "3" | 1 = 3
```

Comment: nice! didn't even thought the precedence has changed

Comment: + has been higher than | since time immemorial --- well, C at least: (see http://www.difranco.net/cop2220/op-prec.htm) What language were you thinking of?

Comment: I know only JS. and my Math sucks, so as far as I know + and - are the lowest in the rank of precedence...

Answer (score 6):

`+` has higher precedence than `|` so you need to put the brackets in to get the order of evaluation that you want.